# Neo4j: Get all relationships between a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j

Let's say I have nodes A and B. I want to find all the paths that connect these two nodes. How would I do it?

Here's an illustration I made. Sorry, I know it sucks lol

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [variable length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) to return all such paths.

For your example (which has relationships pointing in both directions), this query using an undirected variable length relationship should work:

```
MATCH p=(:Foo {id: 'A'})-[*]-(:Foo {id: 'B'})
RETURN p
```

Note, however, that variable length relationship without a reasonable upper bound can take virtually forever or run out of memory. So, depending on your DB characteristics, you should determine and use a reasonable upper bound. For example:

```
MATCH p=(:Foo {id: 'A'})-[*..7]-(:Foo {id: 'B'})
RETURN p
```

To improve performance, it is also generally helpful to specify the possible relationship types along the path, to avoid going down inappropriate paths, as in:

```
MATCH p=(:Foo {id: 'A'})-[:TYPE_A|TYPE_B|TYPE_C*..7]-(:Foo {id: 'B'})
RETURN p
```